# Q: How to smooth out a corner line in a piecewise function of 2 variables?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, functions, smooth-functions, piecewise-continuity

Let \begin{equation}h(x,y)= \begin{cases} 0, x \leq 0  \\ x(10-5y), x>0 \end{cases}\end{equation} be a piecewise smooth funcion, that is continuous everywhere, and smooth everywhere except at $(0,y)$.

My idea is to smooth out this "corner line" possibly by extracting a small domain around it, a stripe of width $2\delta$, for $\delta$ small but positive, and replace this with a function $g$ such that $f$ and $g$ can be glued together into a new function $H$ that is everywhere smooth.

It seems that all similar questions concern single variable functions, so this one seems trickier to me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following works:

$$\begin{equation}h(x,y)= \begin{cases} 0,\ x \leq -\delta  \\ \frac{(10-5y)(x+\delta)^2}{4\delta},\ |x|<\delta \\ x(10-5y),\ x\ge\delta \end{cases}\end{equation}$$

I simply treated $y$ as a constant, turning the function into a single-variable piecewise linear function. The two straight lines can be connected by a parabola, giving the result above.

Comment: It seems to me that even now, we have a point still:

For $x=\delta$, we get $x(10-5y)$ from the right limit, while the left limit gives $4\delta^2(10-5y)$

Comment: @YiorgosPATSIOS Sorry, when writing up my answer I accidentally omitted the division by $4\delta$. Fixed now.

Comment: This is entirely correct. Thanks!